# When I click a marker on Google map it should open multiple markers, but the marker that has been clicked should also appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have written code for Google Maps API where when I click a marker multiple markers should appear, but the marker that has been clicked should also appear. Means the page should not refresh. Please help me. Here is my code where if you click on the marker multiple markers will appear, but the marker disappears.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: 25.2138, lng: 75.8648};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });

        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello World!',
    map: map
});

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    clicktoOpenMAp();
});

marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});


marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
});


      }




            function clicktoOpenMAp() { var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(50);


    var markers = [
        ['chittorgarh', 24.8887, 74.6269],
        ['morak', 24.7265, 75.9739],
        ['mangrol', 25.3362, 76.5112]
    ];



    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }


    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(8);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });


      }




    </script>
<script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='YourGoogleApiBecauseicantsharemine'&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please use your Google API key, because I can't share mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is how I fixed it:

```
      function initMap() {
      var uluru = {
          lat: 25.2138,
          lng: 75.8648
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: uluru
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
      });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: 'Hello World!',
          map: map
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
          clicktoOpenMAp();
      });

      marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, this);
      });


      marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
          infowindow.close();
      });

      function clicktoOpenMAp() {
          //  var map;
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          var mapOptions = {
              mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
          };


          //  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
          map.mapTypeId = "roadmap";
          map.setTilt(50);


          var markers = [
              ['chittorgarh', 24.8887, 74.6269],
              ['morak', 24.7265, 75.9739],
              ['mangrol', 25.3362, 76.5112]
          ];



          for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
              bounds.extend(position);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: position,
                  map: map,
                  title: markers[i][0]
              });


              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                  return function() {
                      infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                  }
              })(marker, i));

              map.fitBounds(bounds);
          }


          var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
              this.setZoom(8);
              google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
          });


      }

  }
```

You were "creating" another map everytime you clicked in the marker (I commented the line so you know), then you need to put the Function clicktoOpenMap inside initmap.

Note: I also added async defer to the script where you call the api

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='YourGoogleApiBecauseicantsharemine'&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

You can hide the markers with

```
markers[i].setMap(null);
```

and to erase them

```
var markers = [];
```

Comment: Here the working example, just add you api key https://jsbin.com/zatoyiy/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: 1 more help how I can hide them again

Comment: I just added it to the answers